# Several problems about running Spark tutorial exapmles

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm currently learning on some tutorials of Spark. I downloaded the latest version spark 2.0.1. The following is the code I recently running in spark-shell:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.createDataFrame

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val people = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0),p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()

// people.saveAsParquetFile("people.parquet")
people.write.format("parquet").save("people.parquet")

val parquetFile = sqlContext.parquetFile("people.parquet")

//Parquet files can also be registered as tables and then used in SQL statements.
parquetFile.registerTempTable("parquetFile")
val teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM parquetFile WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")
teenagers.map(t => "Name: " + t(0)).collect().foreach(println)
```

Let me promise first that I have googled all my questions and didn't find proper result before I come here for asking, cuz I experienced devote on my question for similar reason before. My questions are:

1. what is the difference among `import sqlContext.implicits._` and `import spark.implicits._` and `import sqlContext.createDataFrame` in use?
2. actually I ran that code successfully before, but not this time with nothing changed. The error message i got is too much to show, let me show a part of them:

   > Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@59fa5a39, see the next exception for details.
   >       at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
   >       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
   >       ... 144 more

   I guess the error occurred at the point of `.toDF()`, but don't know why;
3. the last question is that, I heard that `.saveAsParquetFile()` had not been in use anymore. So how should I do to write a parquet file EXCEPT using `.write.format("parquet").save("xxx.parquet")`?

Those questions are the real problems i met, not getting effective solutions. So if you found I can get answer at somewhere, please just share the link to me and do not devote my question without a convincing reason. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about the import statements? The `implicits` are from different  packages. The `sqlContext.createDataFrame` imports that function directly.

Comment: @cricket_007 what i exactly want to know is that the difference of those three when I use them. cuz when I wrote the codes, i found just using  `import sqlContext.implicits._` can meet all i want. so would this mean the others are useless for me?

Comment: For this tutorial, it would appear those are unused, yes. I'm not even sure that you have Spark 2.0 code there. Dataframe was replaced with Dataset. SqlContext is part of SparkSession

Comment: @cricket_007 maybe the tutorial was based on old version. I also get much confusion on version transforms. anyway, thank you for explaining

Comment: You can go to the official Spark webpage and can check the URL to see what version of the documentation you are looking at